# How to output the ASCII string buffer this function stores hex digits into?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

This is code from my assembly language introduction book on how to convert hex to ASCII. I'm a bit confused about how to go about outputting this after calling hexToAscii. I know how to create the output box and message but I'm not sure where the result is stored.

Here is the exact code from the book:

```
; hex to ASCII procedure and test driver
.586
.MODEL FLAT
.STACK  4096
; test driver for hexToAscii procedure
.DATA
source      DWORD   0b70589a4h   ; a sample hex number (as source) to be converted 
dest        BYTE    8 DUP (?)    ; destination with ASCII result after the call 
.CODE
main        PROC
            lea     eax, dest   ; destination address
            push    eax         ; second operand (destination’s address)
            push    source      ; source (1st operand)
            call    hexToAscii  ; hexToAscii(source, dest)
            add     esp, 8      ; discard parameters        
quit:       mov     eax, 0      ; exit with return code 0
            ret
main        ENDP
END            

hexToAscii  PROC
; Convert doubleword to string of eight ASCII codes
; Parameters:
; (1) doubleword containing source value
; (2) doubleword containing destination address of 8 byte long area
            push    ebp             ; establish stack frame
            mov     ebp, esp
            push    eax             ; save registers
            push    ebx
            push    ecx
            push    edx
            mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ; source value to EAX
            mov     edx, [ebp+12]   ; destination address to EDX
            mov     ecx, 8          ; loop count
forIndex:   mov     ebx, eax        ; copy value
            and     ebx, 0000000fh  ; mask off all but last 4 bits
ifDigit:    cmp     bl, 9           ; digit <= 9?
            jnle    elseHex         ; skip if not
            or      bl, 30h         ; convert digit to ASCII
            jmp     endIfDigit      ; exit if
elseHex:    add     bl, 'A'-10      ; convert letter to ASCII
endIfDigit:
            mov     [edx+ecx-1], bl ; store in memory
            shr     eax, 4          ; shift next digit to right
            loop    forIndex        ; iterate loop

            pop     edx             ; restore registers
            pop     ecx
            pop     ebx
            pop     eax
            pop     ebp             ; restore base pointer
            ret                     ; return
hexToAscii  ENDP
END
```

Comment: That function converts a binary integer *to* ASCII hex (a text serialization format), not *from* hex.  Anyway, to print the resulting buffer, same way you'd print a buffer of `char [8]` - depends on what OS you're running under and what library function you want to use.  You could append a `0` and call `puts` on it for example, or use `fwrite`, or a Windows WinAPI call.  Of if this code is part of an OS kernel, copy it to video RAM.

Comment: Thanks Peter for clarifying that it's converting binary integer to ascii. What had me confused was since the sample hex number in source was 0b70589a4h, when I outputted dest and it showed b70589a4, it made me think I was outputting the wrong thing. I added a user input and entered my own binary integer to source and it's outputting what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, hex as a serialization format for binary numbers is very useful for assembly-language source-code.  Your assembler converts those 8 hex digits to 4 bytes of data in the executable, which later gets loaded/mapped into memory when you run it.  Exactly the same thing happens when you use decimal numbers in source code, like `1234`, or even base 2 like `0b010011101`  Or for MASM probably trailing `b` for "binary" actually just text base 2.